# Trying to print exec in python

Tags: python, notepad++

After searching on Stack Overflow all the results i've found have been out-dated.
I'm trying to print out the results of an exec command like the code below shows :

```
code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
print j
""" 
from cStringIO import StringIO
old_stdout = sys.stdout
redirected_output = sys.stdout = StringIO()
exec(code)
sys.stdout = old_stdout

print redirected_output.getvalue()
```

Now i've found out that StringIO is no longer supported. I am using `Python 2.7.6` on NotePad++. Everytime i've tried to import io it's told me the module isn't supported.

Edit: I forgot to mention the script is being loaded into `IronPython` in `c#` and i'm looking to return the value of exec code so I can have a textbox with the output.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what is the issue, your code runs fine once you put `\tprint j`

Comment: Where are the *full* error messages that you get? Also, I don't understand whether the problem is NotePad++ or whether you get a program error. BTW: you do not need to define `old_stdout`. The original value is already stored at `sys.__stdout__`.

Comment: The issue is that the script is being loaded into IronPython in c#. Everything I have compiles it's just returning the output of the execution of code to a textbox in c#. So I was looking for a way to return the output of exec.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `StringIO`.  Also, you need to indent the `print` statement in `code`.  The following will work just fine:

```
code = """
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print j
""" 
exec(code)
```

will output:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: I think I do as it isn't Python running the code, it's IronPython embedded into c#. The way I have it returning the print statement I need it to to the correct text box is using a return statement in python.

Comment: Have a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx